# Having issue with mysql_real_escape_string and before it was fine

Tags: php

I will take an small example of my issue. this code were perfect 6 hours back but now there is some problem and i dont know what it is?

here is my small php. i am able to find out problem is **mysql_real_escape_string** but i dont know how to fix this damn fast.

```
<?php
// database connection
require_once 'includes/inc/config.php';
$date = new DateTime();
$newtime = $date->format('U');
// we are taking post_text = <img id="profile_pic" width="200px" height="600px" src="image/user/1.jpg">
if (isset($_POST['submit-post'])) {
    $content = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['post_text']);
    if ($got != "" && $send != "" && strlen(trim(preg_replace('/\xc2\xa0/',' ',$content))) != 0) {
        $postnow = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `comment`(`send`,`got`,`content`,`time`) VALUES ('$send','$got','$content','$newtime')");
    }
}
?>
```

For display

```
<?php

require_once 'library/all/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';

// reading content which was saved when user posted comment
// getting it from database ex: <img id="profile_pic" width="200px" height="600px" src="image/user/1.jpg">

$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
$content = $purifier->purify($content); 

// and then echo

echo $content;

?>
```

This short of my post display on every page.

Here is my **output** what i get

this is broken image and before it was not broken any idea what has happen?

```
<img id=\"profile_pic\" width=\"200px\" height=\"600px\" src=\"image/user/1.jpg\">
```

PS: this still work fine on localhost. I am bit confused if my server provider upgrade something or like that. I have no idea. Thank you all.

Comment: This is the expected behavior of [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

Comment: What was happening before?

Comment: Before : <img id="profile_pic" width="200px" height="600px" src="image/user/1.jpg">

Comment: The idea of escaping content is to sanitize user input. If you sanitize a string and output it from that script, it will look exactly like that. The escaping is to use user input to run queries, not after. Did you have magic quotes on?

Comment: @DeepakKumar: What *exactly* are you trying to do here?  What *actual* problem are you trying to solve?  Why do you think your "problem" is `mysql_real_escape_string`?

Comment: Solution, stop using the deprecated library mysql_*, and move to MySQLi or PDO with prepared statements.

Comment: Its user comments and they are able to post picture and message. i just took small example of picture. Also i am using HTMLPurifier Library. But problem is with mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: @DeepakKumar: Were you getting that "before" value *from* the database?  When used in an SQL query, the value will be inserted *without* the slashes.  The slashes are just there so that the query will run properly (when you concat this string to it).

Comment: @DeepakKumar The problem is *not* with `mysql_real_escape_string`.  The problem is what you are doing with its result.  `mysql_real_escape_string`'s only purpose is for SQL queries.  That's it.  Using its result outside of an SQL query is incorrect.

Comment: @DeepakKumar Please include the code that retrieves and stores those values from/in the database to clarify your question.

Comment: @RocketHazmat i am now trying to get it from database. but still same problem

Comment: @DeepakKumar: We can't help you unless you show us how you are inserting and retrieving it from the database.  As it stands, the code posted is working as it is supposed to.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I have added more detail on this question.

Comment: @DeepakKumar: When you call `$content = $purifier->purify($content);`, where is the `$content` that you are passing to `purify()` coming from?  Is that the same variable as above (`$content = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['post_text']);`)?

Comment: $content = post_text which is "<img id="profile_pic" width="200px" height="600px" src="image/user/1.jpg">";

Comment: @DeepakKumar: So, then what's your problem?  Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: Problem is its giving : <img id=\"profile_pic\" width=\"200px\" height=\"600px\" src=\"image/user/1.jpg\"> which is broken image. I dont need broken image. and it use to work fine since last 7 month.

Comment: @DeepakKumar: What happens if you `echo $content;` *before* calling `$purifier->purify($content);`?  How are you *getting* it from the database?  You're not trying to escape it or anything when getting it, are you?

Comment: same result : <img id=\"profile_pic\" width=\"200px\" height=\"600px\" src=\"image/user/1.jpg\"> this is what saved in database.

Comment: Thank you every one for trying to short it out. I got to sleep. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 6):

The behavior outlined above is the correct behavior. The function in question

```
mysql_real_escape_string
```

Is meant to sanitize, in specific ways, input in to a MySQL database so you do not get errors on INSERT, UPDATE, etc.